# I have no IP address after resetting my network

Tags: networking, ip, network-adapter

I updated my Windows 10 and I had no issue until I did a reset on the Network. Now I have no IP address on my PC, when I do the `ipconfig` this is what I get

[image]

The `Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection*` both says **Media Disconnected** so I try to navigate to my Network Adapter but I don't see any of the `Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection`

[image]

So I also tried creating a new IP doing the `netsh interface ipv4 add address "Local Area Connection" 192.168.XXX.X 255.255.255.0` but I get this error

```
Failed to configure the DHCP service. The interface may be disconnected.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I also tried so many solutions like updating my Network Adapter, but it says UP TO DATE... I tried resetting my network so many times still no result. I tried so many suggestions including from [Windows 10 - media disconnected on ethernet and wireless adapters](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-media-disconnected-on-ethernet-and/078619ac-fd38-45da-89b5-a9bf5283d7fb) still to no avail.

Please can anyone help me out here, it has been so frustrating for me since yesterday. This is my version of Windows

[image]

Comment: Update your screenshots to reflect your system, connected to a WiFI network, it's not unusual NOT to have an IP address when you are NOT connected to any network.

Comment: So your screenshots are NOT relevant to your actual situation when the problem occurs and you are using the PC as a mobile hotspot at times (which may confuse the issue even further). That doesn't help. Please EDIT your question and add screenshots of the REAL situation when the problem is present. And clarify if this happens when you try to make to use the phone as hotspot for the PC or/and if it happens when connection to a normal Wifi network. We need more (and correct) information about your setup.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are normally using Wifi. (Because wired ethernet is disconnected.)

The Wifi adapter sees signal from a known network (green bars), but you are NOT actually connected to it (it says "Not Connected").

So the Wifi adapter probably has the setting "Automatically Connect" switched off (this sometimes magically happens after a Windows update) and you have to re-connect it.

Only AFTER that has been done the DHCP server can give you an ip-address.

Comment: I have reconnected my PC to a WiFi so many times after updating... Or can u explain better to me, I'm not used to this so I don't know how to go about it

Comment: Click on the network icon in your system-tray. You should see a list of available Wifi networks. Click on your own Wifi network, make sure the check-mark is set next to "Connect Automatically" and then click on the Connect button (and enter the password if needed). From your screen-shots it is clear that you are NOT really connected to the Wifi network.

Comment: Okay... I have done that. In fact that How I set my PC just that it's not connected at the moment of the screenshot.

Comment: Now for example, I turn on my Mobile hotspot on my PC and try to connect my phone to it but it doesn't obtain any IP address... Don't get me wrong here, I didn't say I only connect my phone to my PC, I do turn on any of the mobile hotspot of either my PC or phone and connect the other to it